# How can I add multiple MKAnnotation to a map using geocodeAddressString?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mapkit

I'm starting to program on Swift and I've already built a couple simple apps.

I'd love to have a view in my App that displays two cities (or more) using MKAnnotation. I've seen that there's a function called geocodeAddressString() from CLGeocoder. I've found this function incredibly useful since I don't need to know the coordinates of any place to make an annotation: I just write the city and it appears in the map.

I've already searched on Google and there are some solutions with coordinates, but not with geocodeAddressString() in particular. I've read Apple's documentation and looks like its an asynchronous function. My code is the following:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setUpMap()
    }

    func setUpMap(){
        
        var points: [MKPointAnnotation] = []

        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString("Paris, France", completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            if let location = placemarks?.first?.location {
                annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
                points.append(annotation)
            }
        })
        
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString("Sophia, Bulgaria", completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            if let location = placemarks?.first?.location {
                annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
                points.append(annotation)
            }
        })
        
        self.map.addAnnotations(points)
        
        
    }
}
```

Obviously, since function is asynchronous the behaviour of this code is not the one I'm expecting (only the first city gets added). I guess this could be done with closures but I'm not sure how. Any help is appreciated!

- I've read Apple's documentation
- I've tried adding @escaping together with a closure but it didn't work
- In a desperate attempt to make it work, I wrote a recursive function that would add to an annotations array one city and then it would call itself again for the next city (stored in an array of cities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLGeocoder`'s documentation says:

> Send at most one geocoding request for any one user action.

In order to only send one request at a time, we can take advantage of async/await. The code may look like this:

```
func setUpMap(){
    Task { @MainActor [weak self] in
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

        do {
            let req1: [CLPlacemark] = try await geoCoder.geocodeAddressString("Paris, France")
            if let location = req1.first?.location {
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
                self?.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
            let req2: [CLPlacemark] = try await geoCoder.geocodeAddressString("Sophia, Bulgaria")
            if let location = req2.first?.location {
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
                self?.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        } catch {
            // handle errors
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to use multiple `CLGeocoder`s:

```
func launchRequest(_ address: String) {
    Task { @MainActor [weak self] in
        do {
            let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
            let req: [CLPlacemark] = try await geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address)
            if let location = req.first?.location {
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
                self?.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
                print("Annotation: ", annotation, location.coordinate)
            }
        } catch {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}

func setUpMap(){
    launchRequest("Paris, France")
    launchRequest("Sophia, Bulgaria")
}
```